# SQL splitting time when over midnight

Tags: sql

I am after some guidance on the best way to get useful information out of our MIS database

Scenario:- I want to check staff utilisation by a variable period that I can drill down into. This needs to then be split into days so I can assess over a 24 hour period what was done

The table is huge and has loads of columns we need to calculate, so ideally I need to split the records that span 2 days into 2

The table has a datetimeformat field that has user [starttime], it then has a separate field that has [duration] which is in decimal hours.

So an example would be:

```
ID   StartTime              Duration      Qty      username
1    2016-11-24 23:00:00       2.00       1000      Joe Bloggs
```

In the example above Joe starts at 11pm and works till 1 am, so what I need is to somehow split this record in my query to put anything before midnight as 1 record and anything after into another This example is pretty simple as it is half/half but some might start at 10pm and finish at 6pm so I would need 2 hours and 6 hours.

Not sure on the best way to do this, my initial thoughts was to create a cte where a start time is in 1 day and if the starttime + duration was in the next day then split the record.

Not sure if there is an easier way or if anyone has had to do this before.

Any help appreciated

Comment: `control - k` or add 4 spaces to format as code

Comment: what `id` would you use for the split record? same as original? Please show us a sample of the output after the split.

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: Assuming no duration exceeds 24h, you basically want a UNION of two SELECTS: one returns all rows, with the duration until midnight, the other returns rows WHERE (start time + duration > 24h), with start time set to midnight on day + 1.  If you're having trouble expressing this in SQL, post sample DDL and DML and I'm sure someone will give you a query.

Comment: @joe The only problem would be the ID. In the second `select` I would do something like `100000000 + ID as ID` to create the ID for the split row.

Comment: What should be the QTY of the second row?

Comment: Which DBMs are you using?

Comment: answers will vary depending on which platform you are using.  are you using sql-server, oracle, mysql, ....?

Comment: You REALLY need to tell us WHICH database! Date/Time functions vary dramatically by dbms vendor

Answer (score 0):

@Joe has the right idea, here is pseudo-SQL

```
SELECT ID,StartTime,Duration,Qty,username
WHERE TRUNCATE(StartTime,DAY) = TRUNCATE(StartTime + Duration hours ,DAY)
 UNION
SELECT ID,StartTime, TRUNCATE(StartTime,DAY) + 1 days - StartTime hours ,Qty,username
WHERE TRUNCATE(StartTime,DAY) < TRUNCATE(StartTime+Duration hours,DAY)
 UNION
SELECT ID,TRUNCATE(StartTime+Duration hour,DAY),StartTime + duration hours - DATE(StartTime+Duration),Qty,username
WHERE TRUNCATE(StartTime,DAY) < TRUNCATE(StartTime+Duration hours,DAY)
```

Where `TRUNCATE(timestamp,DAY)` truncates a timestamp to `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply rows with `join`. Make Tally table, simple table with numbers 1, 2, 3... and do a join. I will use table starting at zero here:

```
CREATE TABLE Tally0 (Number INT IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO Tally0 DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10000
```

Now the harders part is conversion between dates and numerics:

```
;WITH 
tmp1 AS (SELECT *, 
           DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATE, StartTime), StartTime)/3600.0
           + DATEPART(NANOSECOND, StartTime)/(3600*1000000000.0) AS startingHours
         FROM Record),

tmp2 AS (SELECT *, 
           startingHours + Duration AS endingHours,  
          (startingHours + Duration)/24.0 AS endingDays  
         FROM tmp1)

SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN Number = 0 THEN StartTime 
         ELSE DATEADD(DAY, Number, CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)) 
    END AS StartTime2,

    CASE WHEN Number = 0 AND 1 < endingDays THEN 24 - startingHours
         WHEN Number = 0 THEN Duration
         WHEN Number + 1 < endingDays THEN 24
         ELSE endingHours - Number * 24 
    END AS Duration2

FROM tmp2 
JOIN Tally0 ON Number < endingDays
```